# Uncaught TypeError: utils.convertToMomentFormat is not a function

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

Whenever I go, within the *Magento admin*, to *Content > Blocks*, there is this error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: utils.convertToMomentFormat is not a function`.

The file path is

> myshop.com//pub/static/version1523976842/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date.js

The code:

```
prepareDateTimeFormats: function () {
  this.pickerDateTimeFormat = this.options.dateFormat;
  if (this.options.showsTime) {
   this.pickerDateTimeFormat += ' ' + this.options.timeFormat;
  }

  // This is the "problem" line
  this.pickerDateTimeFormat = utils.convertToMomentFormat(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);

  if (this.options.dateFormat) {
    this.outputDateFormat = this.options.dateFormat;
  }

  this.inputDateFormat = utils.convertToMomentFormat(this.inputDateFormat);
  this.outputDateFormat = utils.convertToMomentFormat(this.outputDateFormat);

  this.validationParams.dateFormat = this.outputDateFormat;
}
```

What is the cause of this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and admin started to work again.